# Is there a way to know if gremlin query is read query or write query

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

I am trying to add basic read/write authorization in gremlin-server, I want to know if there is a way by which I can identify if this query is read-only query or write query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no API call you can make to determine that, but you can get inspiration for how to detect it from `ReadOnlyStrategy` [here](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/37e6349bb956d4f8f99e6beef9d66d3c36d166dc/gremlin-core/src/main/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/strategy/verification/ReadOnlyStrategy.java). The key is to cycle the `Traversal` object and look for a `Step` that implements the `Mutating` interface. If you find one of those in there, you could classify the traversal as a write query.

Of course, for Gremlin, classifying a query and read or write isn't so binary as it could easily be a mix of read and write. It's also possible that at runtime the write might never execute depending on the flow of the traversal, so it could be "runtime readonly". Hopefully, detecting the `Mutating` interface is a good-enough solution for you.

I'm not sure where you intend to implement this authorization function but I sense it would be best done as a `TraversalStrategy` that would then fire on traversal execution. I don't know if that's too late for your authorization process, but it would be the easiest way I can envision. The problem is that if you are accepting scripts then with that approach you could get a partial execution of that script up to the point where authorization was not allowed. If you needed to disallow an entire script based on one write traversal then you might need to look at a [custom sandbox](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#script-execution). Of course, it is better to avoid scripts altogether and simply use bytecode based requests only. If you are only concerned with bytecode then `TraversalStrategy` should work pretty well for the authorization use case.

Comment: thanks a lot @stephen-mallette for the guidance. For now, we can disallow scripts altogether. I am adding authorization after authentication, adding it as a separate step because in case of websocket, we perform authentication once but have to implement authorization on per request. Any query that has write Step is write query for me even if it is "runtime readonly" query.

Comment: Now, I have to convert this gremlin query in String to List of Steps, I am referring code of TraversalOpProcessor for that. Is there any better way?

Comment: As I go to explain to you how to best do this, I see a few obstacles in your path that make this harder to do that it should be despite the ease with which you can check for a mutating traversal and with scripts disabled. I have a suggestion that is an easy workaround and requires the least amount of code and change, but it may not fit your use case. Simply, configure two traversal source instances, one with `ReadOnlyStrategy` and one without. In your authorization step, authorize the user against the traversal source they intend to use to ensure they can do so. Will that work?

Comment: thanks @stephen-mallette, I believe it will work for us, let me try it.